# How to fill select options from a directive?

Tags: angular

Here is a simple select:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="..." name="..." id="..." required ...>
   <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o.value">{{o.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Options is initialised like this:

```js
class MyComponent() {
    options;
    constructor(someService: MyService) {
        this.options = someService.getAllOptions();
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Everything works fine. However the problem is that I need this select with exactly the same options at various locations. So there are many components which all have this `options`-Property and load it from my service. That's a lot of code repetition I would like to avoid.

Obviously a component is an option, so that I can just write `<mySelect ...>`, but the downside is, that I need to pass thru many other variables such as `id`, `class`, `name`, `required` and possibly more attributes. So I'd prefer a directive-solution, so I can write `<select [(ngModel)]="..." name="..." ... myDirective>` and `myDirective` should just add the options as needed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In a directive you have easy access to the HTML element using an `ElementRef`-Parameter and thus adding the element options is no problem. The key is, that you need to register the options with the `SelectControlValueAccessor`. Usually an `<option>`-Element is recognized by angular at compile time and an `NgSelectOption` is created [which registers itself in the constructor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/57f7996b6d2bee5a63902637fdec5b60b9a857cd/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L214). Since you created that option element dynamically you need to do this step manually:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
    constructor(someService: MyService,
                element: ElementRef<HTMLSelectElement>,
                renderer: Renderer2,
                @Optional() @Host() select: SelectControlValueAccessor) {

        someService.getAllOptions().forEach(co => {
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = co.displayName;
            option.value = co.id;
            element.nativeElement.add(option);
            new NgSelectOption(new ElementRef(option), renderer, select); 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old question, but I think it's worth the share.

Improving on [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413889/how-to-fill-select-options-from-a-directive#answer-55413890), the Angular way is not to interact directly with the global `document`, but instead, use its built-in [Renderer API](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(
    someService: MyService,
    element: ElementRef<HTMLSelectElement>,
    renderer: Renderer2,
    @Optional() @Host() select: SelectControlValueAccessor
  ) {
    // remove previous options
    this.element
      .nativeElement
      ?.childNodes
      .forEach((node) => this.renderer.removeChild(this.element.nativeElement, node));

    someService.getAllOptions().forEach(co => {
      // prepare the option element
      const option = this.renderer.createElement('option');
      const text   = this.renderer.createText(co.displayName);
      this.renderer.setValue(option, `${co.id}`);
      
      // add the option text under option, and option element under select
      this.renderer.appendChild(option, text);
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.element.nativeElement, option);

      // make the directive play nice with Angular forms
      const ngOption = new NgSelectOption(new ElementRef(option), renderer, select);
      ngOption.ngValue = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Advantage of this is that it's easier to port your code to run in environments that don't have DOM access, such as when you do server-side rendering, or build for native mobile, or run as a service worker.